# Call Powershell Script from Unix Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, powershell

I have a powershell script on my Windows server which does some active directory operations. I wish to call that script from another Linux machine using a shell script.

I have installed powershell server on my Windows server and can communicate with my linux machine using *key based ssh authentication*.

Since Windows does not support SSH connections on its own, I have installed a software called Powershell server (http://www.powershellserver.com/) on my Windows server.

The issue is that my script just stops once the command for ssh to Windows server is executed.

My shell script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script run"
GROUP=$1
ACCOUNT=$2
ssh Administrator@<Windowshostname>
sleep 10
echo "<pathtoscript>\scriptname.ps1 -group $GROUP -account $ACCOUNT"
sleep 5
echo "exit"
exit
```

I have tried without the echo command as well and it still hangs. Any idea what I must be doing wrong here? How can I make it work please?

Comment: I think you just need `ssh Administrator@Winhost "sleep 10; /path/to/script -group $GROUP -account $ACCOUNT"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ssh into a Windows box unless you install a SSH daemon.
You have two options:

1- You need to connect via [Remote PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) (WINRM).

2- Install SSH daemon and connect via SSH (Check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/638659/managing-windows-powershell-from-linux-terminal))

3- You can also use [PowerShell Web Access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/14/step-by-step-deploy-powershell-web-access.aspx) (Windows Servers.)

**UPDATE**: If you are using PowerShellServer.com then there are some things you can do to try to understand more.

- Test **scriptname.ps1** locally in Windows Server
- Edit your **scriptname.ps1** in the first line to create a file somewhere and after execution check if that file exists. This way you will know if script is being executed or not.
- Execute **Get-ExecutionPolicy** and check you can run scripts. Remove constraints by temporary **Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted**

Comment: I can connect to the Windows box using the ssh command as I have installed powershell server on my Windows VM.

ssh Administrator@<Windowshostname>
PowerShell Server: SSH-Enabled PowerShell Access for Windows (powershellserver.com)

PS C:\ProgramData>

Comment: But Windows by default doesn't allow SSH. What have you installed to vanilla Windows?

Comment: You should edit your question and add that information as it is relevant.

Comment: Just did. I cannot use power shell web access as it has to be through a Unix shell script only. I have to use that script in another implementation.

Comment: Yep. I can execute my script locally. I am doing some Active directory operations and that works well on local execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the operation using an "expect" script and it all works well now.